# How to pass a scenario outlines with different parameters?

Tags: loops, testing, automated-tests, python-behave

I am using behave to do my tests.
I want to play my scenario outlines with others parameters, a scenario outlines inside a scenario outlines in some words.
I have

```
Scenario outlines : Test John access
   Given John enters
   When He could access to <area>
   Then the access is <result>

   Examples:
      | area      |  result       |
      | parking   |  authorized   |
      | security  |  refused      |
```

I don't want to do copy this test for each employees.
I want to loop this like :

```
Scenario outlines : Test user autorization
   Given all my employees :
        | name      |
        | John      |
        | Jack      | 
        | Lisa      |
 
   Scenario outlines : Test user access
      Given <employee> enters 
      When He could access to <area>
      Then the access is <result>

      Examples:
      | area      |  result       |
      | parking   |  authorized   |
      | security  |  refused      |
```

How i could do it ?
Thanks in advance for your ideas.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer would be to also add the `employee` to the Examples table. You wouldn't have to copy the test, but you would still have to multiply the number of rows if you want to test all areas for each employee:

```
Examples:
      | employee  |  area      |  result       |
      | John      |  parking   |  authorized   |
      | John      |  security  |  refused      |
      | Jack      |  parking   |  authorized   |
      | Jack      |  security  |  refused      |
      | Lisa      |  parking   |  authorized   |
      | Lisa      |  security  |  refused      |
```

This, however, also allows you to test different privilege levels per user.

Comment: This is also the conclusion I found. We think the same.  A scenario outline with one fix user for testing all his access might another way.